# How to open different page for different combobox value on one submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i make two  combo box in html on for case type and other for revision and one button for submit form ,second combo box have 2 value revision1 and revision2 i want when user select from revision1 from combo box second then open home page
and when user select from combo box second revision2 and submit then open contact page.
how can i do .please help me thankyou

```
      <form  name="causeform" method="post" action="">

      <fieldset>
         <select id = "myList" name= "casetype" class="form-login" style="width:250px;" >
           <option value = "D">D</option>
           <option value = "E">E</option>
           <option value = "A">A</option>
           <option value = "C">C</option>
           <option value = "F">F</option>
           <option value = "S">S</option>
           <option value = "B">B</option>
           <option value = "W">W</option>
           <option value = "T">T</option>
           <option value = "R">R</option>
         </select>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
          <select id = "myList" name="revision" class="form-login" style="width:250px;">
           <option value = "0">R0</option>
           <option value = "1">R1</option>
           </select>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" style="margin-left:90px;width:103px;height:42px;" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
var valu = $('#my-dropdown').val();    
if(valu== 1)
{
    var url = 'http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com';
    $(location).attr('href', url);
}    
if(valu== 2)
{
    var url = 'https://www.google.co.in';
    $(location).attr('href', url);
} 
if(valu== 3)
{
    var url = 'http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/default.aspx';
    $(location).attr('href', url);
}        
});
```

[Demo:Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSyF2/21/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location.href to redirect to destination pages based on Selection of revision

for example on click on submit button you can check

```
$('#submitButtonId').click(function(){
if( $('.class2').val() == 0) {
// open home page
} else if ( $('.class2').val() == 1) {
// open contact page
}

});
```

Please give different class for each select box for jquery selectors

There are many ways you can do it , By using hidden field , you can store the value of dropdown 2 and use this hidden value to compare on submit

Comment: sir thanx for giveing me solution but how can i give different class for one combo box.give some coding example

Comment: In Your code you have assigned Same Id to both select box , That's wrong